# WebFlux Flux.cache() how long cached emitted data is stored

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Context:
I have a finite Flux which is source of Rest API Call, and this flux is in scope of main REST API call made to my Spring Boot Application which returns Mono with response. I would like to reuse response of this Rest API for two subscriptions. I've found that Flux cache() is solving this task, but the question is:

How long the data emitted by first subscription will be stored in memory if there are no ttl duration specified? Should we clear somehow this cache to avoid memory leaks, or it will live only in scope of specific outer main HTTP Request(Subscription to Mono which will trigger inner Flux subscription) and will be cleared after termination of Flux?

Didn't find in documentation any details about this: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#cache--

Comment: with this signature (no params), it claims "unbounded volume" (unlike  the overload alternatives)..

Comment: From my understanding unbounded volume it is about count of emitted elements by Flux which should be cached. But what about ttl or lifecycle for those events in memory? @xerx593

Comment: ..there are six overloads of this method... just scroll the docs

Comment: I've checked docs, and it looks like ttl for cache without params will be 0, but it is not still clear enough, will it be stored indefinitely in memory and I will catch OOM after some time if application won't be restarted or not.

Comment: Logically, it cannot be longer than an active subscription. But since the caching makes sense only for a shared flux look at how long it keeps it active. I guess it's till the last subscriber consumes the data.

Comment: Igor is completely right, after last subscriber finished consuming data, cached emitted data is removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Igor Atamanov mentioned, emitted data which was cached without specified ttl will be stored in memory until last subscriber which will subscribe and reuse this flux won't complete his subscription.